# To prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n} \cos(λx) \, dx＝0$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

Let $λ$ be a real number, then,
I would like to prove the following.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^n} \cos(λx) \, dx＝0$$

My attempt:
$-e^{-x^n}≦e^{-x^n} \cos(λx)\le e^{-x^n}$, but integral of $e^{-x^n}$ from $0$ to $∞$ cannot be $0$, so this estimation meaningless..
Integration by parts? More complicated..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the limit is $0$? I think it should be $\tfrac{\sin \lambda}{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the integral in two:
$$I_n:=\int^\infty_0e^{-x^n}\cos\lambda x\,dx=\int^1_0e^{-x^n}\cos\lambda x\,dx +\int^\infty_1 e^{-x^n}\cos\lambda x\,dx$$

On $[0,1]$, $|e^{-x^n}\cos\lambda x|\leq 1$ and $e^{-x^n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$ Thus by dominated convergence
$$\int^1_0e^{-x^n}\cos\lambda x\,dx\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0\cos\lambda x\,dx$$

On $(1,\infty)$, $|e^{-x^n}\cos\lambda x|\leq e^{-x}$ and $e^{-x^n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. Thus, by dominated convergence
$$\int^\infty_1e^{-x^n}\cos\lambda x\,dx\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does ":=" mean?

Comment: @Axel: in my side of the Atlantic (North America) it means equals as a definition, for example, define $f(x):= \text{some expression}$.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense to me now! (+1) for your answer by the way.