# When $n$ is a fixed real number, then $\lim_{λ\to\infty} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^n} \cos(λx) \, dx＝0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis

Let $n$ be a fixed real number, then,
How to prove the following?
$$\lim_{λ\to\infty} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^n} \cos(λx) \, dx＝0$$

My attempt:
$-e^{-x^n}≦e^{-x^n} \cos(λx)\le e^{-x^n}$, but integral of $e^{-x^n}$ from $0$ to $∞$ cannot be $0$, so this estimation meaningless..
Integration by parts? More complicated..

This question look very similar to this,
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175162/to-prove-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-infty-e-xn-cosλx-dx＝0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175162/to-prove-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-infty-e-xn-cos%CE%BBx-dx%EF%BC%9D0)

But in this question, $n$ is fixed and $λ→∞$.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Integration by part should work.

Comment: This is a special case of the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma. As jvc said, integration by parts should do the job.